# I wanna use concerns without line in routes.rb

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I use the concern and include him on application controller

```rb
class ApplicationController
  include ErrorHandling
end
```

```rb
module ErrorHandling
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, with: :not_found
  end

  def not_found
    render plain: 'Not Found', status: :not_found
  end
end
```

But i need add the row in my routes.rb by

```rb
get '*path', to: 'application#not_found', via: :all
```

And when i wrote this line my query all is good and 404.html static page is render

When i delete this line my query is

```
Starten GEY "/123" for 127.0.0.1 at ....

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/123"):
```

I wanna delete this line but how do this work? I dont now how
It work on rails 6 without this line in routes.rb

I do all that i write

Comment: My file named as error_handling.rb my class name is ErrorHandling

Comment: Usually, this kind of error handling is disabled in development and test mode and only active in production. Do you experience those issues in production too? Or only when running your code locally?

Comment: No only in development enviroment can i do ``get '*path', to: 'application#not_found', via: :all if enveroment.production?`` or something else

Comment: How can I easily enable this? I made config.public_file_server.enabled = true in my development environment, but the static files from public are not rendered

Comment: Please do not post images of code, input/output data or error messages. Copy them (using the copy functionality of your OS) and paste them as text in the question.

Comment: you can't rescue `ActionController::RoutingError` in controllers. that error is raised in the middleware before it can reach any controller.

Comment: I remove all images sorry for this pls i really dont now this

Answer (score 2):

When you want to those exceptions handling in development like in production, then you need to set [`consider-all-requests-local`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#config-consider-all-requests-local) to `false`.

From the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#config-consider-all-requests-local):

> **3.2.16 config.consider_all_requests_local**
>
> Is a flag. If true then any error will cause detailed debugging information to be dumped in the HTTP response, and the `Rails::Info` controller will show the application runtime context in `/rails/info/properties`. `true` by default in the development and test environments, and `false` in production. For finer-grained control, set this to false and implement `show_detailed_exceptions?` in controllers to specify which requests should provide debugging information on errors.